# how to dynamically adjust height in chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, devexpress

I am using [chartjs](http://chartjs.devexpress.com/) for my web application currently. I am having an issue when initializing the chart with a large amount of data. I am using a rotated bar chart, and it is removing some of my arguments fields when re sizing the chart. this results in the arguments not lining up with the correct bars. I cannot seem to find an option that allows for the height of the chart to dynamically adjust.

is there a way to achieve this so that I am able to see all of my arguments?

Comment: Share more your implementation details/code here.